# What does "occasions" mean in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

> The justiciarship originated in the king’s need for a responsible subordinate who could take a wide view of the affairs of the kingdom, act as regent when the king was abroad, and on other **occasions** take charge of those matters with which the king had no time to deal.
>   — Encyclopedia Britannica

Does the word *occasions* in the above sentence mean "circumstances, occurrences, or states of affairs that provide ground or reason for something" or "special events or ceremonies"?

Comment: At other times/circumstances where the king was not able or willing to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's at the end of a listed series, where "catch-all" phrases are usually put, I would interpret it as being the first, more general, definition ("circumstances, occurrences, or states of affairs that provide ground or reason for something").